# Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0 error when trying to add Firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I want to connect my app of Android Studio to Firebase but I am getting this error:

> Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0

This is my current screen:
[image: Current screen]

Is there anything wrong here?

```
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
    }
```

I have tried cleaning the project and run it again. It didn't make a change.

I have tried removing

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

and changing it for:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

with the three of them separately the error goes away, but the Firebase dependency is not setting up.

Comment: Try to add last version `implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'`

Comment: And apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' to last line after closing dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this instead of using a lower version.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
```

For more you can follow this: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android